# Оптимизация базы данных Postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть база данных в Postgres, сейчас около `3 000 000` строк (будет намного больше) вот несколько из них:

```
pub         text                                            data
68264400    А Вот теперь точно пятница!)) Наслаждаемся!))   {"attachments": [{"video": {"photo_640": "https://pp.userapi.com/c845216/v845216380/da477/4oBhrXMZu78.jpg", "comments": 0, "views": 307, "owner_id": -169532875, "platform": "YouTube", "duration": 611, "photo_130": "https://pp.userapi.com/c845216/v845216380/da474/7u2HeQg5m_s.jpg", "photo_320": "https://pp.userapi.com/c845216/v845216380/da476/4U1VesXEhRs.jpg", "id": 456239037, "date": 1535127680, "description": "\u0421\u043c\u0435\u0448\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044b Best COUB # 15 | \u041a\u043e\u0443\u0431 | Cube | \u0410\u0432\u0433\u0443\u0441\u0442 2018 |  \u0410\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0435/\u0416\u0438\u0432\u043e\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0435/Game/Wins - CoubHUB\n\n\u2605 \u041f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u044c \u043b\u0430\u0439\u043a \u2764  \u042d\u0442\u043e \u043e\u0447\u0435\u043d\u044c \u043d\u0430\u0441 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0438\u0442!\n...", "title": "\u0421\u043c\u0435\u0448\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044b Best COUB # 15 | \u041a\u043e\u0443\u0431 | Cube | \u0410\u0432\u0433\u0443\u0441\u0442 2018 | \u0410\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0435/\u0416\u0438\u0432\u043e\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0435/Game/Wins -CoubHUB", "access_key": "0d46fb35e0aa617fb7", "can_add": 1, "photo_800": "https://pp.userapi.com/c845216/v845216380/da477/4oBhrXMZu78.jpg"}, "type": "video"}], "post_source": {"platform": "iphone", "type": "api"}, "views": {"count": 3085}, "likes": {"can_publish": 1, "user_likes": 0, "can_like": 1, "count": 3}, "text": "\u0410 \u0412\u043e\u0442 \u0442\u0435\u043f\u0435\u0440\u044c \u0442\u043e\u0447\u043d\u043e \u043f\u044f\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430!)) \u041d\u0430\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0436\u0434\u0430\u0435\u043c\u0441\u044f!))", "from_id": -68264400, "signer_id": 499274352, "comments": {"can_post": 1, "groups_can_post": true, "count": 3}, "id": 80487, "date": 1535193628, "marked_as_ads": 0, "reposts": {"user_reposted": 0, "count": 1}, "post_type": "post", "owner_id": -68264400}
```

Пока все переменные типа `TEXT`, знаю, что это не рационально, но пока не могу переделать, так как:

1е значение может быть не только числом, но длинна не больше 20и символов

2е значение текст с неизвестной длинной

3е значение это тоже `TEXT` с json

Сейчас запросы типа `select * from база where pub=id` работают ну ооочень долго, около 8 секунд на запрос. Могу ли я как-нибудь существенно увеличить время? Сильно ли поможет переделать первый столбец под varchar или что-то численное? И сильно ли поможет убрать третий столбик?

Comment: У вас точно основная проблема в `data` поле. Т.к. там JSON то его вам надо распарсить и все данные из него разложить по разным таблицам. И сделать связь через промежуточную таблицу с записями из текущей. Так в текущей останется всего 2 поля - `pub` и `text` - должно всё значительно ускориться.

Comment: А какие индексы у вас построены на таблице ? Что то не верится, что поиск по индексу на поле pub может выполняться 8 секунд ...

Comment: Всем будет проще, если вы добавите в вопрос DDL таблицы и результат выполнения explain analyze медленного запроса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я создал новую базу на основе этой и перенёс туда поля pub и text. Да, действительно, скорость сильно увеличилась, спасибо. Есть ли еще какие-то советы по оптимизации?

Comment: @Mike, как я могу узнать эту информацию? Я еще ньюбби в базах, к сожалению

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, как я могу получить DDL?

Comment: А в чем с БД работаете ? Есди pgAdmin, то там просто в менюшке находите нужную таблицу и нажав на нее справа видите весь DDL, со всеми индексами. (вообще DDL это те команды, которыми вы таблицу создавали). Ну и там же у таблицы можно отдельно индексы посмотреть. В общем по полю pub должен быть или индекс или он должен быть первичным ключем

Comment: @Mike, я спросил о том, как узнать индексы. Если я правильно понял, то в документации описывается время и функции по работе с ним. А так, я только что загуглил этот вопрос, создал индекс и теперь получаю ответы на запросы моментально. Спасибо